# Count Method on Undefined Active Record Array @objects.count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is there a way to write a clean if nil then in a view. Assuming my lack of ruby is biting me here. Example,

If object nil, then return, nothing found

have

```
<%= @objects.count if @objects %>
```

want something like this

```
<%= @objects.count if @objects then "nothing found" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to write something like this.

Something simple would be:

```
<% if @objects %>
  <%= @objects.count %>
<% else %>
  nothing found
<% end %>
```

If you get into a slightly more complex conditional I would suggest moving the logic into a helper and call it from the view. ex:

```
<%= count_for(@object) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good solution for you:

```
<%= "nothing found" unless @objects.try(:length).to_i > 0 %>
```

One of the issues is that you can't run `count` on a nil object. Therefore you need to use Rails' super handy `.try()` method to return nil when `@objects = nil`, rather than `NoMethodError`.

Next issue: You can't make a comparison between `nil` and a number using `>` so you need to convert the results of `@objects.length` to an integer which will return 0 for nil.

Lastly, try calling `length` rather than `count`. This will avoid running any extra queries when `@objects` is defined.

Avoids: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'objects'`

Also if you want to display the count using this one-liner technique you can simply write up a shorthand if/else statement as follows:

```
<%= @objects.try(:length).to_i > 0 ? @objects.length : "nothing found" %>
```

**One last option:**

Use the pluralize method, which can handle a nil count:

```
Showing <%= pluralize( @objects.try(:length), 'object' ) %>
```

Sorry, I know this is pretty late, but hopefully helpful for someone else!

Comment: That seems overly confusing and samtically wrong. If the `try` call returns nil, you are essentially asking if 0 is greater than 1.

Comment: Changed to use .to_i as I think it's clearer. Thanks for your feedback